# (Python 3.x) Web scraping code taking upwards of an hour to load

Tags: python, python-3.x

Webpages in my browser are taking seconds to load, but this program has not completed after almost an hour of it running

```
import urllib

baseurl = 'https://www.google.com/?finance?q='
stocksName=['dow','apple','cat']
i=0
while i<len(stocksName):
    fileurl = baseurl + stocksName[i]
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(fileurl)
    text = file.read()
    print(text)
    i+=1
```

Edit: I noticed when I say print(text[0:100]) it finishes in a reasonable amount of time. Is it just the print() thats causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You've a typo (`fullurl`) and my guess is that your `while` loop only finishes when the script times out.

Change from

```
file = urllib.request.urlopen(fullurl)
```

to

```
file = urllib.request.urlopen(fileurl)
```

Comment: sorry, re-wrote the code on my other computer (because my laptops dead) in the actual code it wasn't a typo. It printed the html file of all the pages, it just took over an hour for it to finish

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me when the `fileurl = baseurl + stocksName[i]` is added together we get `https://www.google.com/finance?q=DOW`

this is actually the finance website for the entire search of DOW (3629 Companies results)

Maybe add `stocksName = ['NYSE:DOW']` to your list and remove `'dow'`

This could be the cause of the problem.

If that does not solve the problem try targeting specific pages:

```
import urllib

baseurl = 'https://www.google.com/finance?cid='
stocksName=['665819','22144','5736']
i=0
while i<len(stocksName):
    fileurl = baseurl + stocksName[i]
    file = urllib.request.urlopen(fileurl)
    text = file.read()
    print(text)
    i+=1
```

Comment: took it out, same problem

Comment: For dow are you targeting https://www.google.com/finance?q=665819? or the entire DOW search?

Comment: I took out dow, same problem, but when I put in print(text[0:100]) it finished in a reasonable amount of time, so I think its a problem with the print function

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get from this web scrap? I ran your code and it took about 2 minutes to complete and gave me all the html information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be network related. Perhaps you were blocked from accessing the site on the server side or some other issue which causes your urllib request from not completing successfully. (Blocked your useragent)?

Try using the timeout feature, because by default urllib.request will wait forever to complete the request.

```
file = urllib.request.urlopen(fileurl, timeout=5)
```

You may find that your request is timing out. Another guess to the root cause is using https with urllib which is out dated. Try using the "requests" library.

Example request:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')
print(r.status_code)
```